# CSS Seletor - Executar um laço a partir de um determinado item do laço

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, lógica, seletores

Bom dia. Digamos que eu tenho uma tabela com 100 linhas, mais gostaria que meu each (JQuery) começasse a partir da linha 15. Qual seletor Css Deveria usar? Ou JQuery possui algum recurso para tal?

Valeu a todos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe sim um seletor CSS. Seguindo seu exemplo de uma tabela com 100 linhas `tr`, você poderia usar algo deste tipo:

```
tr {
    background: gray;
}
tr:nth-child(n + 15) {
    background: blue;
}
```

Neste caso você estaria dizendo que todas as linhas da sua tabela teriam por padrão um fundo cinza, mas que o fundo seria azul a partir da linha 15. **Basta aplicar este exemplo no seu each JS.**

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a função `slice` do próprio javascript `Array`.

A função funciona da seguinte forma:

Tenho um array `[12, 32, 31, 23, 43]` e quero pegar somente a partir do terceiro, ou seja, quero pegar somente as posições `[31, 23, 43]`, então neste caso faria assim: `[12, 32, 31, 23, 43].slice(2)`, ou seja, eu cortaria fora as duas primeiras posições do array.

Sendo assim, no seu caso ficaria assim:

```
$('.seu-seletor').slice(15).each(function() { /* PERCORRENDO O ARRAY */ });
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Não pretendo cortar fora os itens, somente retira-los da seleção. Mais valeu, ajudou também!

Comment: Opa, que bom que ajudei de alguma forma! Abraço!